# Pre-requesties for teradata installation in Windows 7 32 -bit

Tags: windows-7, installation, teradata

I am planning to trigger teradata using Java in net-beans. For that, I need to use teradata database. Can anyone clearly say what are all the prerequisites needed for installing it in Windows 7, 32 bit desktop. Since I am new to this I can't understand it clearly. Can anyone help me with this? I have also gone through teradata website too.

Answer (score 1):

Teradata actually runs on SUSE Linux Enterprise server.  To run on windows you would need to be running Teradata Express in a VM.  However, Teradata express requires 64 bit.

So it sounds to me like you are out of luck. Even if you install Teradata Express and run it in a VM you are really only emulating a 2 node teradata installation.  You aren't going to get robust performance.  This solution is really only suitable for a small learning environment.

The system requirements and download are found here:
http://www.teradata.com/teradata-express/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment:-)

Comment: Be sure to accept the answer if it addresses your question completely.